# How to find $\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}(p+x^2)^{-3} dx$ where $p>0$

Tags: calculus, integration

Need help with this calculus problem.

> Compute the integral:
>   $$\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}(p+x^2)^{-3} dx$$
>   where $p$ is a fixed positive number.

May someone give full solution.It is in [here](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~oholtz/191/) (HW#1) and it is not homework because it is due a month ago.

Comment: Victor, in the past 40 minutes you posted **three** questions. All of which seem to be copied out of some textbook or homework sheet. It would be better if you added on *each* of these questions some information about: (1) Where the problem originates; (2) What did you try to do on your own.

Comment: *Tell me and I forget. Show me and I remember. Involve me and I understand* is [somebody's excellent motto](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/12796/victor).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As usual, I try a *special function approach* to the problem.

You have:
$$\tag{1} \begin{split} \int_{-\infty}^\infty (p+x^2)^{-3}\ \text{d} x &= \frac{2}{p^3}\ \int_0^\infty (1+x^2/p)^{-3}\ \text{d} x \\ &\stackrel{u=x^2/p}{=} \frac{1}{p^{5/2}}\ \int_0^\infty \frac{u^{-1/2}}{(1+u)^3}\ \text{d} u\; ;\end{split}$$
keeping in mind that the integral defining the [*beta function* $B(t,s)$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) can be put in the form:
$$B(t,s)=\int_0^\infty \frac{u^{t-1}}{(1+u)^{t+s}}\ \text{d} u$$
when $t,s>0$, the rightmost side of (**1**) equals $1/p^{5/2}\ B(1/2,5/2)$. Finally, since:
$$B(t,s)=\frac{\Gamma (t)\ \Gamma (s)}{\Gamma (t+s)}\; ,$$
[$\Gamma (1/2)=\sqrt{\pi}$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_values_of_the_gamma_function#Integers_and_half-integers) and:
$$\Gamma (1+t)=t\ \Gamma (t)\qquad \text{(hence } \Gamma (1+n)=n! \text{ for positive integers)}$$
(where $\Gamma (\cdot)$ is [*Euler gamma function*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function)), you get:
$$\begin{split} \int_{-\infty}^\infty (p+x^2)^{-3}\ \text{d} x &= \frac{1}{p^{5/2}}\ \frac{\Gamma (1/2)\ \Gamma (5/2)}{\Gamma (3)}\\ &= \frac{1}{p^{5/2}}\ \frac{\sqrt{\pi}\ (\frac{3}{2}\ \frac{1}{2}\ \sqrt{\pi})}{2!}\\ &= \frac{3\pi}{8\ p^{5/2}}\; .\end{split}$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let $x=\sqrt{p}\tan\theta$.  Then $dx=\sqrt{p}\,\sec^2\theta\,d\theta$. Our integral after a while becomes 
$$\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \frac{\sqrt{p}}{p^3} \cos^4 \theta\,d\theta.$$
The integration is now maybe familiar. One can do it by parts, or by using double-angle identities.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Differentiate twice with respect to $a$ both sides of the identity $$\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \frac{1}{x^2+a^2} dx = \frac{\pi}{a} .$$